# Mapping data to a list when I have the position index

Tags: c#, csv, dictionary, csvhelper

(I'm using CSVHelper package)

Hi,

I have an array of `sbyte[]` that holds the position of each header column in a CSV file. The array is defined as follows,

`public sbyte[] ColumnIndex = new sbyte[Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum)).Length];`

and say I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
name1,empId1,241682-27638-USD-CIGGNT ,1
name2,empId2,241682-27638-USD-OCGGINT ,1
name3,empId3,241942-37190-USD-GGDIV ,2
name4,empId4,241942-37190-USD-CHYOF ,1
name5,empId5,241942-37190-USD-EQPL ,1
name6,empId6,241942-37190-USD-INT ,1
name7,empId7,242066-15343-USD-CYJOF ,3
name8,empId8,242066-15343-USD-CYJOF ,3
name9,empId9,242066-15343-USD-CYJOF ,3
name10,empId10,241942-37190-USD-GGDIV ,2
```

Now calling the byte array and passing the `Enum` index would give me back where that position in the header row:

`int conversion = (int)MyEnum.col3;`

`ColumnIndex[conversion]);`

`returns 2`

Now this all works fine, but I seem to struggle to figure out how to map each column with its info to separate `List<string>` based off the position index I have.

I tried to put all fields in a single `List<string>` using this code:

```cs
 public List<string> ParseEntire(aliasType type, string PathToFile) {

            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            using (TextReader fileReader = File.OpenText(PathToFile)) {
                var csv = new CsvReader(fileReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                string value;
                while (csv.Read()) {
                    for (int i = 0; csv.TryGetField<string>(i, out value); i++) {

                        result.Add(value);
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

However, that's useless because I won't be able to know the position of every header. I feel like there is an easier way to do it using the `CSVHelper` package and I'm just complicating a simple task. Any Help would be appreciated.

EDIT: 
For the following Emun

```cs
  public enum aliasType {
            col5,
            col4,
            col3,
            col2,
            col1
        }
```

After executing the code to map the position indices to `ColumnIndex`, it would look like this:

```cs
ColumnIndex  {sbyte[4]}
[0]             [-1]
[1]             [3] 
[2]             [2]
[3]             [1]
[4]             [0]
```

I'm mainly doing this because I do not know what the header row contains. So, I extract as much info as I can and when I get back an index of -1, I know that that specific field doesn't exist.

UPDATE:

the following code uses the `Intersect` to compare against different aliases for the same header column I'm trying to extract.

```cs
 public List<string> HeaderColumnParser(aliasType type, string PathToFile) {

            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            using (TextReader fileReader = File.OpenText(PathToFile)) {
                var csv = new CsvReader(fileReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                CSVBOM extract = new CSVBOM("", CSVBOM.BOMFileType.csv);

                csv.Read();
                csv.ReadHeader();
                string[] header = csv.Context.HeaderRecord;
                IEnumerable<string> CommonHeaders;

                foreach (aliasType foo in Enum.GetValues(typeof(aliasType))) {
                    int res = Convert.ToInt32(foo);

                    switch (res) {
                        case 0:
                            // get matching string
                            CommonHeaders = header.Intersect(ReferenceDesignatorAliases);
                            ColumnIndex[res] = extract.ExtractIndexHeader(CommonHeaders, header);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            CommonHeaders = header.Intersect(ManufacturersPartNumberAliases);
                            ColumnIndex[res] = extract.ExtractIndexHeader(CommonHeaders, header);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            CommonHeaders = header.Intersect(ValueAliases);
                            ColumnIndex[res] = extract.ExtractIndexHeader(CommonHeaders, header);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            CommonHeaders = header.Intersect(DescriptionShortAliases);
                            ColumnIndex[res] = extract.ExtractIndexHeader(CommonHeaders, header);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            CommonHeaders = header.Intersect(DescriptionLongAliases);
                            ColumnIndex[res] = extract.ExtractIndexHeader(CommonHeaders, header);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            CommonHeaders = header.Intersect(ManufacturerAliases);
                            ColumnIndex[res] = extract.ExtractIndexHeader(CommonHeaders, header);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            CommonHeaders = header.Intersect(DNIAliases);
                            ColumnIndex[res] = extract.ExtractIndexHeader(CommonHeaders, header);
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            CommonHeaders = header.Intersect(DataSheetAliases);
                            ColumnIndex[res] = extract.ExtractIndexHeader(CommonHeaders, header);
                            break;
                        default:
                            throw new Exception("Alias type is not recognized");
                    }
                }

            }
            return result;
        }
```

My Enum and array of strings for the aliases:

```cs
   public enum aliasType {
            ReferenceDesignatorAliases,
            ManufacturersPartNumberAliases,
            ValueAliases,
            DescriptionShortAliases,
            DescriptionLongAliases,
            ManufacturerAliases,
            DNIAliases,
            DataSheetAliases
        }

        //Returns -1 meaning not found
        public sbyte[] ColumnIndex = new sbyte[Enum.GetNames(typeof(aliasType)).Length];

        public string[] ReferenceDesignatorAliases = { "Reference Designator", "RefDes", "Designator", "Annotation" };
        public string[] ManufacturersPartNumberAliases = { "Manufacturer's Part Number", "MPN", "PN", "part Number" };
        public string[] ValueAliases = { "Value" };
        public string[] DescriptionShortAliases = { "Description Short", "Description" };
        public string[] DescriptionLongAliases = { "Description Long" };
        public string[] ManufacturerAliases = { "Manufacturer", "MF" };
        public string[] DNIAliases = { "DNI", "Do Not Install" };
        public string[] DataSheetAliases = { "DataSheet", "Data Sheet" };
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Does `ColumnIndex` have a different order for the columns than the CSV file does?

Comment: The way I have is that after I pass in the Enum value of the header column I want the position for and it returns that position. I will edit my answer to explain this more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have a little better idea of what you are trying to accomplish. Let me know if this solves your issue.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("MF,RefDes,MPN,Value");
        writer.WriteLine("name1,empId1,241682-27638-USD-CIGGNT ,1");
        writer.WriteLine("name2,empId2,241682-27638-USD-OCGGINT ,1");
        writer.WriteLine("name3,empId3,241942-37190-USD-GGDIV ,2");
        writer.WriteLine("name4,empId4,241942-37190-USD-CHYOF ,1");
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        string[] ReferenceDesignatorAliases = { "Reference Designator", "RefDes", "Designator", "Annotation" };        

        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();

        var result = new List<string>();

        if (csv.Context.HeaderRecord.Intersect(ReferenceDesignatorAliases).Count() > 0)
        {
            while (csv.Read())
            {
                if (csv.TryGetField(csv.GetFieldIndex(ReferenceDesignatorAliases), out string value))
                {
                    result.Add(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Here is another option that gets all of the columns at once and then you can split them up into the individual column lists.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Foo> records;

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("MF,RefDes,MPN,Value");
            writer.WriteLine("name1,empId1,241682-27638-USD-CIGGNT ,1");
            writer.WriteLine("name2,empId2,241682-27638-USD-OCGGINT ,1");
            writer.WriteLine("name3,empId3,241942-37190-USD-GGDIV ,2");
            writer.WriteLine("name4,empId4,241942-37190-USD-CHYOF ,1");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<FooClassMap>();

            records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();                
        }

        if (!records.All(r => r.ReferenceDesignator == null))
        {
            var ReferenceResult = records.Select(r => r.ReferenceDesignator).ToList();
        }

        if (!records.All(r => r.Manufacturer == null))
        {
            var ManufacturerResult = records.Select(r => r.Manufacturer).ToList();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string ReferenceDesignator { get; set; }
    public string ManufacturersPartNumber { get; set; }
    public int? Value { get; set; }
    public string DescriptionShort { get; set; }
    public string DescriptionLong { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Dni { get; set; }
    public string DataSheet { get; set; }
}

public class FooClassMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooClassMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.ReferenceDesignator).Optional().Name("Reference Designator", "RefDes", "Designator", "Annotation");
        Map(m => m.ManufacturersPartNumber).Optional().Name("Manufacturer's Part Number", "MPN", "PN", "part Number");
        Map(m => m.Value).Optional();
        Map(m => m.DescriptionShort).Optional().Name("Description Short", "Description");
        Map(m => m.DescriptionLong).Optional().Name("Description Long");
        Map(m => m.Manufacturer).Optional().Name("Manufacturer", "MF");
        Map(m => m.Dni).Optional().Name("DNI", "Do Not Install");
        Map(m => m.DataSheet).Optional().Name("DataSheet", "Data Sheet");
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer. This seems to get the index based off where the header name is in the Enum. My problem is that I do not know how the header fields are organized and some might be even missing. I will update my question with the code I use to find the position regardless of the arrangement.

Comment: I updated my answer.  It should handle columns that are not there, as well as different names for the columns.

Comment: That worked for me but I was wondering since I have to do it for multiple alias arrays, can I point back to the beginning of the file because csv.Read() is returning false when I try to read using the second set of alias arrays.

Comment: You could set the `stream.Position = 0`, but I would try and get them all within `while (csv.Read())` rather than looping back through the file again.